# Matrix in exponent

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, series-expansion

If, for example, matrix A given as

$A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & x & z \\
  0 & 0 & y \\
  0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}$

By power series expansion one can obtain

$e^A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x & z+\frac{1}{2}x y \\
  0 & 1 & y \\
  0 & 0 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}$.

Is Mathematica able to calculate such a thing? E^A simply does not work.

Comment: See `MatrixExp` and `MatrixPower` for matrix related powers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @eyorble says in his comment, use [`MatrixExp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp):

```
MatrixExp[{{0,x,z},{0,0,y},{0,0,0}}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & x & \frac{1}{2} (x y+2 z) \\
>  0 & 1 & y \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$